# Run 2 different apache servers on the same machine with different ports?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-server

I would like to know if it's possible to have two apache server and able to set it for two different port, for example: 192.168.0.1:80 and 192.168.0.1:81.
If it is possible, how to do it?
For information, I'm on an ubuntu server machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible by configuring virtual hosts in apache, something like this...

```
    Listen 80
    Listen 81
    
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/app1"

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "/www/app2"

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 different apache servers installed on same PC but only one works at a time. I tried to set port 8080 for first server and port 80 for second one and tried to start both but only one works at a time. So my answer is No you cant unless you run second via VM. If it really works then share solution with me as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).